# Div disappears after applying ng-repeat property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to fetch the data from a Json API and display it on user event. The div disappears whenever I apply ng-repeat property to it? I tried to look through different tutorials and other docs but can't find the answer.
Please help.
Thanks.

My Html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Football News</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet"> 


    <!--AngularJs CDN-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="homeController as home" ng-init="home.loadAllMatches()">
        <div class="mainContent">
            <div class="header">
                <span>Primier League</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="matchList" ng-repeat="round in home.rounds">
                    <div class="matchListContent" ng-repeat=" match in round.matches"> 
                        <span>{{ match.name }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="angular/Controller/mainController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Js:

```
 var footballApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

footballApp.controller('homeController',['$http', function($http){
    var self = this;
    this.matches = [];
    console.log(this.matches);

    this.baseUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json";

    this.loadAllMatches = function(){

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: self.baseUrl
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            self.matches = response.data.rounds;
            console.log(self.matches);

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            alert("Some error ocurred. Check Console");
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

}]);``
```

You can see the Json Api via this Link: [EPL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json)

Comment: You're iterating an undefined variable. `round in home.rounds`. You don't specify `rounds` anywhere in your `controller`. You' d probably want iterate at `home.matches` instead.

Comment: @Korte `home.matches` maybe, since `home` is the scope for the controller

Comment: Yes... mistyped :p

Answer (score 0):

> when rendering data you are not binding the value properly,below code
>   might be usefull for you

**controller**

```
var URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json'
            $http.get(URL).then(function(response) {
                $scope.dataset= response.data;

            });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="value in dataset.rounds">
        <div ng-repeat = "x in value.matches">{{x.team1.name}} , {{x.team2.name}}</div>
</div>
```